# Dash to dock making overview large

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell-extension, dash-to-dock

I was doing some customizations. Installed dash-to-dock(latest) and this happened. My ubuntu version is latest 20.04.2 LTS with fully upgraded softwares and drivers. I also had [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310312/screen-getting-zoomed-in-automaically-while-booting?noredirect=1#comment2229974_1310312) issue which I think is related with this (actually... I don't know). So kindly reqesting help on this one.

- **Disabling dash-to-dock (without using dock) ->**
  [image: image before]
- **Disabling dash-to-dock (with using dock) ->**
  [image: image before 2]
- **Enabling dash-to-dock (with/without using dock) ->**
  [image: image after]

Comment: That probably would lead me not to use Dash to dock, but rather use the build in Ubuntu Dock. It is based on Dash to Dock and can thus be configured to the same extent by editing the /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/ configuration settings.

Comment: @vanadium No I can't there is no dash to dock settings in just dock. I need to customize it.

Comment: @vanadium did you mean editing dash-to-dock always results in the customization of ubuntu dock

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu dock uses the same gsettings

Comment: Okay Then I will go on with your answer. (Answer it below if you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to be an issue with the "Dash to dock" Gnome Shell extension, perhaps just in combination with your Ubuntu versions and customisations. Actually, you may then work around by using the build in Ubuntu Dock. It is based on Dash to Dock and can be configured to the same extent. Only are the settings not exposed to the user. You can still change them using `dconf-editor` by editing the /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/ configuration settings. Alternatively, you may keep Dash to Dock installed, and set configuration in Dash to Dock. When finished, turn Dash to Dock off and turn Ubuntu Dock.

It you did install Dash to Dock through the Gnome Website, there is something else you may try. Remove the extension, then reinstall it, but this time through the software center: `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock`. Because this version is packaged in the Universe repository by the Ubuntu developers, there is a good chance that issues with the version from the website are not there.